# How to forward a PHP closure to another controller

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a very basic routing class and learn PHP closures by example. Basically, I want to make a routing feature like in Laravel but only with using closures.

```
function get($uri)
{
   if($uri == '/account')
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}

function Boo()
{
  echo "Boo";
}

$route = new Route();

$route->get('/account', function() { 
   return $route->Boo();
});
```

I can do this without closures and see "Boo" as output.

How can I do this with closures? I currently see a blank output.

Ps. Functions are in correct class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually accept the closure as a parameter of your get method, and call it, here's an example

```
class Route
{
    function get($uri, Closure $closure=null)
    {
        if($uri == '/account')
        {
            // if the closure exists, call it, passing it this instance as its parameter
            if (null !== $closure) {
                $closure($this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function Boo()
    {
        echo "Boo";
    }
}
$route = new Route();

// have the closure accept a route as it's parameter
$route->get('/account', function($route) { 
    return $route->Boo();
});
```

Comment: So, we define which function to be called inside our closure, but calling that function is made by the get function, right? That's what PHP supports, or just a way to solve my problem? Because, then I have to give Router class access to other classes, like my controllers so it can start the appropriate functions inside controller classes. However, then my Router class will depend on controller classes to run properly. I believe it's a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, you can do whatever you need to inside your closure, but ultimately you have to actually call it somewhere. In your use case, it appears you want to call it when you pass it to the get method, so that's where I've placed it.

Comment: Where could be that somewhere else, if it's not a callback check inside the get function?

Comment: Wherever makes sense for your application needs. You seem to be trying to make closures fit without actually knowing if they suit your needs. Perhaps step back and figure out what you need and then use the most appropriate way to get the job done.

Comment: Well, we pass it as a second parameter to our get function inside Route class. How may anything else can access it if it's a value in a function scope?

Comment: I've no idea, I don't know how your application works. I've given you a working example based on what you asked. You're straying into theoretical discussion about programming concepts now, which is probably better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com or maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you have code and want advice on how to improve it.